# unique ids are not in sequence in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make a database primary key. I am using PHP uniqid() Function.

```
uniqid(php,true);
```

Basically I want to add Student IDs in student table of database

e.g PHP-16-001

In which **PHP** is 3 character Course ID , **16** is year and **001** is student ID.

I can Add this via "."

```
$id = "php"."date('Y')".$i;
```

in which $i is a variable who is incrementing but when I fetch data from database I got

php16001

How can I got all characters?

Comment: `echo "PHP-".date('y-').$i;`

Comment: I tend not to use meaningful values as a primary keys.
Also you could use 3 different columns and make the primary key a combination of them: `CREATE TABLE t  (courseId VARCHAR(3), year YEAR, studentId INT,
     PRIMARY KEY (courseId , year , studentId ) 
  ) `

Comment: I think you're overthinking this. What's wrong with using a pivot table with an auto increasing primary key that would store the course id, the year, and the student id, then just reference the pivot table's id in all instances which you'd need a concatenation of the credentials. That way if anyone ever gets their hands on the key, it would be useless outside of the scope of MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String concatenation operator in php is '.', so to get your extra '-' characters add them to you string, Check the below code. You should insert your unique id in database as "php-16-001". Make sure your $i variable is a string.

```
$id = "php-" . date('y-') . $i;
```

Comment: I can got like this but what I do when i retrieve data from mySQLi and want to separate all parts again?

Comment: use php explode() function

Comment: *brr* Codd didn't die for this! :) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form

Answer (score 1):

A better way to do it:

```
if($i < 9)
{
    $i='00'.$i;
}

$unique_id = "PHP-".date('Y')."-".$i;
```

Answer (score 1):

Separate them by some character which you can then split by.

```
$id = sprintf("php-%s-%s", date('Y'), $i);
```

To "split" it back to individual chunks use `explode`

```
$idParts = explode("-", $string);
```